# Unable to format Python string while decoding from dict to str

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

I have a dict which I am encoding as a string as such:

```
import json

template = json.dumps({
    '_index': '{0}',
    '_type': '{1}',
    '_id': '{2}',
    '_source': {
        'doc': '{3}',
        'doc_as_upsert': True
    }
})
```

Now, I try to format it as per the new python conventions mentioned here: https://pyformat.info/

`print template.format('one','two','three','four')`

However, I get an error as so

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "python", line 1, in
>    KeyError: '"_type"'

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Formatting a json representation of data is a bad idea. Format the data itself instead.

Comment: @Rawing complete answer would be more useful!

Comment: @tsaebeht dude's just trying to help, show some manners.

Comment: @patrick I honestly made no sense of his comment. Trying to help would be writing a well formatted answer, not throwing comments around. I have taken the effort to put up a readable question for the community, I would except the same as per rules on SO.

Comment: what prevents you from doing: `'_index': '{0}'.format('one')` inside the `json.dumps` `dict` definition? Are you asking **how** to do it or **why** your approach is not working?

Comment: Your problems are caused by curly braces after `_source`. Its contents is interpreted as a substitution key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem stems from the curly braces in your JSON - you need to double-escape them in order for `str.format()` to work, e.g.:

```
import json

template = json.dumps({
    '_index': '{0}',
    '_type': '{1}',
    '_id': '{2}',
    '_source': {
        'doc': '{3}',
        'doc_as_upsert': True
    }
})

template = template.replace("{", "{{").replace("}", "}}")

print(template.format('one','two','three','four'))
```

It will no longer err, but it will also escape your parameter curly braces so they wont get replaced by `str.format()`, so you'll have to invent your own 'parameter' escape as well (make sure it doesn't appear as the markup code for JSON, tho, like curly braces do), for example using `<` and `>` instead:

```
import json

template = json.dumps({
    '_index': '<0>',
    '_type': '<1>',
    '_id': '<2>',
    '_source': {
        'doc': '<3>',
        'doc_as_upsert': True
    }
})

template = template.replace("{", "{{").replace("}", "}}").replace("<", "{").replace(">", "}")

print(template.format('one', 'two', 'three', 'four'))
```

But it's much better idea to directly replace your data before turning it onto JSON. You can call `str.format()` on each (`str`) `value` in your `dict` individually, passing a `dict` with all the parameters to it and using named parameters (i.e. `{one}`) to pick up the needed argument from expanded keys.

**UPDATE**: You don't even need to recurse through your data for the last one as the `json` serializer is going to recurse through it anyway, but unfortunately the `json` module doesn't make it easy to swap the default behavior of string serializing so you'll have to do some monkey-patching:

```
from json import dumps, encoder

def template_json(data, args, **kwargs):
    json_s1, json_s2 = encoder.encode_basestring, encoder.encode_basestring_ascii
    encoder.encode_basestring = lambda s: json_s1(s.format(**args))
    encoder.encode_basestring_ascii = lambda s: json_s2(s.format(**args))
    try:
        return dumps(data, **kwargs)
    finally:
        encoder.encode_basestring, encoder.encode_basestring_ascii = json_s1, json_s2
```

It essentially temporarily wraps the internal JSON string building methods with the ones that apply formatting first and then reverts back everything so that other functions that may depend on the `json` module don't get unexpected behavior (although there is a little danger here, too - this is not thread-safe). Since it will be reading the elements one by one we cannot really use positional formatting so this uses named formatting as suggested above. You can test it as:

```
data = {
    '_index': '{one}',
    '_type': '{two}',
    '_id': '{three}',
    '_source': {
        'doc': '{four}',
        'doc_as_upsert': True,
    }
}

template_vars = {"one": "value 1", "two": "value 2", "three": "value 3", "four": "value 4"}

print(template_json(data, template_vars, indent=4))
```

Resulting in:

```
{
    "_source": {
        "doc": "value 4",
        "doc_as_upsert": true
    },
    "_index": "value 1",
    "_id": "value 3",
    "_type": "value 2"
}
```

But, generally, if you have to *hack around* your system to achieve what you want - you might want to reconsider if that's the right approach in the first place and can your objective be achieved in a simpler manner?